# How can I make a main URL with sub URL for different Django app?

Tags: python-3.x, django, url

I want to make a main URL and that URL will be the main route for all my Django apps.

Suppose I have 3 apps: **blog, linux and business**. I want to make URLs like this:

127.0.0.1:8000/blog/ (when i will click blog menu) 
127.0.0.1:8000/blog/linux ( when i will click linux menu)
127.0.0.1:8000/blog/business (when i will click business menu)

The blog app will be my index home page and all the apps' links will be like this. I don't want to import all of the views and models in the **blog** app. The project's structure will be the same and I don't want to change it.

All I want is to make **blog** common for all the apps. If I click a post on a linux page, the URL will be like this:

127.0.0.1:8000/blog/linux/post name

How can I do this?

This is my project's structure:

[[image: project structure image]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write all the URLs into the urls.py in your project folder or you can make a urls.py in your apps folder. [Maybe read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/)

Answer (score 0):

After Creating the App in django project by following procedure in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

- App Folder (blog app folder, found inside project folder)

Add these urls
127.0.0.1:8000/blog/linux
127.0.0.1:8000/blog/business
to the app/urls.py file above the admin.site url path

- Project Folder:

Configure the urls.py file in the project folder by adding the 127.0.0.1:8000/blog/  url above the admin.site url path. This configuration is done to load this url when the server starts running.

The django checks for the requested url pattern and will route the first discovered url.
The django cannot identify duplicate url.